# Scala type classes for transform on option using higher order functions

Tags: scala, option-type, typeclass, higher-order-functions, existential-type

I have some options that when they are none I want don't want to run my transform function over.

The method which currently handles the options looks like this:

```
def writeOptionalXml[T](content: Option[T], mapFn: T => Xml): Xml =
  content match {
    case Some(c) => mapFn(c)
    case None => NodeSeq.Empty
}
```

And it works great. But I also have other inputs that aren't options but can still be empty, for example an empty string, an empty xml node or some case class.

I thought it would be a good learning experience for me to refactor into a type class. After much code wrangling I discovered I needed to use context bounds to handle the option type, and thought I was well on the way to achieving my type class dreams.

Where I get stuck is the transform function (badly named in example as mapFn).
In the none option case I want the method signature:
(content: Option[T], mapFn: T => Xml): Xml
whereas in the other cases:
(input: A, mapFn: A => Xml): Xml

I have struggled with changing the type signatures, using [_] to try and get what I want but to no avail.

The synthesized version of code I have at the moment, which is anything but pretty, looks like this:

```
import scala.annotation.implicitNotFound

object writableTypes extends App {

  type Xml = String
  @implicitNotFound("No member of type class in scope for ${T}")
  trait WritableLike[A] {
    def toXml[B](input: A, mapFn: ((_$1) forSome {type _$1}) => Xml): Xml
  }

  object WritableLike {

    implicit object WritableLikeString extends WritableLike[String] {
      override def toXml[B](input: String, mapFn: ((_$1) forSome {type _$1}) => Xml): Xml =
        mapFn(input)
    }

    implicit def OptionFormat[T: WritableLike]: Object = new WritableLike[Option[T]] {
      override def toXml[B](input: Option[T], mapFn: ((_$1) forSome {type _$1}) => Xml): Xml =
        mapFn(input.get)
    }

    def writeXml[X](input: X, mapFn: ((_$1) forSome {type _$1}) => Xml )(implicit ev: WritableLike[X]): Xml =
      ev.toXml[X](input, mapFn)
  }

  println(WritableLike.writeXml(Option(SomeCaseClass(5)), transformToXml))

  case class SomeCaseClass(content: Int) { def someMethod = ""}

  def transformToXml[T](input: SomeCaseClass): String = input.someMethod

}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't compile because in this method call
    WritableLike.writeXml(Option(SomeCaseClass(5)), transformToXml)

the function transformToXml doesn't satisfy the required method signature.

I have tried so many permutations of this and can't find a solution, elegant otherwise.

I am sure there are easy ways to solve it by making everything an Option, but I am more interested in finding the solution to making it truely generic.

I am not sure I have explained this very well, it's my first attempt at writing a type class, I thought it would be straightforward but it seems like the particular problem I am trying to solve has some additional complexities.

I'd be very grateful to hear from someone with a deeper understanding of generic programming with the Scala type system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a bit hung up with the `mapFn` in your type class that you used in the plain function. You can structure your type class to rely on the input data only. The rest of the work is done using the instances of the type class. Here's an example of the `WritableLike` type class definition that relies only the input data:

```
trait WritableLike[A] {
  def toXml(input: A): String
}
```

For this example, I'm using `String` in place of the XML type. Using this definition, we can define some simple type class instances:

```
implicit val stringWritableLike: WritableLike[String] = new WritableLike[String] {
  def toXml(input: String): String = s"<text>$input</text>"
}

implicit val intWritableLike: WritableLike[Int] = new WritableLike[Int] {
  def toXml(input: Int): String = s"<integer>$input</integer>"
}
```

In the code above, I defined type class instances for the `String` and `Int` types. Both instances directly define how the input for method `toXml` is transformed to an XML string without relying on another function to provide the transformation. This means that when we apply the type class for either of the types, we will always use the same transformations regardless of the value.

If we want to overload the transformation for certain values, we want to wrap those values with some other type, and provide a type class instance for the type.

```
case class Name(name: String) extends AnyVal

implicit val nameWritableLike: WritableLike[Name] = new WritableLike[Name] {
  def toXml(input: Name): String = s"<name>${input.name}</name>"
}
```

Here we define a case class for representing names and a specific type class for transforming names to XML.

I defined these instances as values, but I might as well have used a `def` or an `object`. The important part is that the instances are implicit regardless of which of these keywords is used. The implicitness allows us to later acquire these instances without referring to them explicitly.

There are cases when you have to use a `def` rather than a `val` for defining a type class instance: it's needed when your type class instance depends on another type class instance. We can use `Option` as an example:

```
implicit def optionWritableLike[A](implicit instanceForA: WritableLike[A]): WritableLike[Option[A]] =
  new WritableLike[Option[A]] {
    def toXml(input: Option[A]): String = input match {
      case Some(a) => instanceForA.toXml(a)
      case None => "<empty />"
    }
  }
```

In the code above, we defined a type class instance for the `Option` type that works on all values where the `Option` type parameter also has a type class instance. Here we represent the inner type as the function type parameter `A`. Since we don't know what `A` is, we need to some way get a type class instance for that type. We can achieve this by adding an implicit parameter for the exact type class instance we need. Finally, using the implicit instance, we can convert the underlying value to XML.

The implicit parameter for the type class instance creates a dependency between the instance and the instance of the type parameter. If the instance for the type parameter exists, we can use the instance that depends on it. If not, we can't use the instance.

There is an alternative syntax we can use to declare the type class dependency:

```
implicit def optionWritableLike[A: WritableLike]: WritableLike[Option[A]] =
  new WritableLike[Option[A]] {
    def toXml(input: Option[A]): String = input match {
      case Some(a) => implicitly[WritableLike[A]].toXml(a)
      case None => "<empty />"
    }
  }
```

Here we declare the type class dependency as part of the type parameter definition. The declaration `A: WritableLike` implies that the type parameter must have a type class instance for the type class `WritableLike` in order to work. We can access the instance using Scala's keyword `implicitly`. The `implicitly` call is a little bit verbose, so it is customary to define a helper function in the type class's companion object:

```
object WritableLike {
  def apply[A: WritableLike]: WritableLike[A] = implicitly[WritableLike[A]]
}
```

Now we can access the type class instance like this: `WritableLike[A].toXml(a)`

The helper method can also help when using the type class outside of the instance definitions:

```
WritableLike[String].toXml("foobar")               // <text>foobar</text>
WritableLike[Int].toXml(123)                       // <integer>123</integer>
WritableLike[Name].toXml(Name("Alan"))             // <name>Alan</name>
WritableLike[Option[String]].toXml(Some("foobar")) // <text>foobar</text>
WritableLike[Option[Int]].toXml(None)              // <empty />
```

Comment: I hope this answer helps. If you have any questions, just comment here, and I'll see if I can expand my answer. :)

Comment: Hi Jaako thanks for your answer.

In the wider context there are several formatters, and each generates xml NodeSeqs from a combination of case classes, strings, dates, other nodeseqs etc(as NodeSeq). Occasionally there are empty strings, nodeseqs or Option[caseclass] of None.

Sometimes a case class is used in multiple places (per formatter) to generate different parts of the xml document, with different xml tags, so the flexibility of generating the node with a passed function is crucial.

Comment: The business case is fine however I wanted to explore the power and limitations of the type class pattern in Scala.

Maybe this is a limit of the language or pattern ?

It just feels like it should be possible.

Comment: You can try to encode those contexts using types as described in my answer (the `Name` type). Type classes tend to be useful when types are used for dispatching the function calls. If you still feel like type classes are too much trouble, plain functions should do just fine. :-)